# Tagged nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_post

Tags: python, tags, nltk

Hi I'm working with the NLTK, nps_chat corpus.

I know that I can access the nps chat corpus like following

```
posts = nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_posts()
```

I prepared Labeled_names list, as following

```
Labeled_names=[(post.text,post.get('class')) for post in posts]
```

And I got following as this,

```
>>> Labeled_names[:10]
[('now im left with this gay name', 'Statement'), (':P', 'Emotion'), ('PART', 'System'), ('hey everyone  ', 'Greet'), ('ah well', 'Statement'), ('NICK :10-19-20sUser7', 'System'), ('10-19-20sUser7 is a gay name.', 'Accept'), ('.ACTION gives 10-19-20sUser121 a golf clap.', 'System'), (':)', 'Emotion'), ('JOIN', 'System')]
```

What I need to know is, instead of just the text, is there is a way to get the tagged text, using nltk.corpus.nps_chat.xml_post?

Comment: Do you mean POS tagged text? If so, use the `nltk.pos_tag()` for tagging the text.

Comment: No. NPS chat corpus is already tagged. What I need to do is is there a way to get those tags as I got the text using post.text

Comment: Only `nltk.corpus.nps_chat.tagged_posts()` is tagged.

Comment: Got it . Thanks alot. That's what I wanted to know

Comment: @DYZ Actually it's doable, and not even very hard. (Answer below.)

Answer (score 1):

The `nps_chat` API doesn't provide a simple way to see POS tags and post metadata at the same time, but it's a matter of a one-liner to navigate the XML elements returned by `xml_posts()` and get this information. Here's a little demo:

```
from nltk.corpus import nps_chat

for p in nps_chat.xml_posts()[3:5]:
    print(p.get("class"), p.get("user"))
    print(p.text)
    tagged_words = list((t.get("word"), t.get("pos")) for t in p[0]) # <-- here it is
    print(tagged_words)
    print()
```

Output:

```
Greet 10-19-20sUser59
hey everyone  
[('hey', 'UH'), ('everyone', 'NN')]

Statement 10-19-20sUser115
ah well
[('ah', 'UH'), ('well', 'UH')]
```

Each `xml_post` has a unique element `terminals`, containing a series of elements `t` each of which has `word` and `pos` attributes. Full path: `Session/Posts/Post/terminals/t`. So the `terminals` element is `p[0]`, and we iterate over its children to get their word and POS tag.